# How can a website running on a browser on an android device access a triggered intent of the device through browser?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, android-intent, honeywell

Whenever an intent is triggered by some activity that can be accessed by an application on android.

But how can an website running on browser, say chrome, access the intent of the android device?

[Intent to be accessed - page 46](https://ipsiscan.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/ScanPal_EDA70_UG_RevA_EN.pdf)

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76455628/21563685)